# Check if an iterator is valid for a QT container

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

Does any trick exist how to check whether an iterator (STL or Java style) is still valid for `QMap` or `QList`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: After changing the container by another thread. I know that I can make external flag for that, but I am guessing can we use encapsulated features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The whole point of iterators is that they are *independent* of any containers. It is up to you to ensure that you only mutate a container if nobody else still has any iterators or references to the container's elements (subject to the container's iterator/reference invalidation specification).

Comment: The whole point of my question is that state of iterators implicitly depend on their containers. QT library partly solve this issue by copying containers (cloning) while iterator alive. But it helps not everywhere.

Comment: @DmitryKachko: OK, I should restrict my answer to the STL-style iterators. It looks like the Java iterators do carry some connection the container. In any event, you have to check the *container*'s documentation -- I don't think that a container would track all iterators and signal them when they become invalid.

Comment: Ok but it could have method to check for validity, for example. Strange that such a method doesn't exists, but I'm asking may be there is some trick to raise exception or something.

Comment: Think about it this way: If an iterator is already invalid, then you mustn't use it at all - so in particular, you cannot perform any querying operations on it. So in order to inform the iterator of a state change from the container, the *container* would have to inform the iterator. But that would require that the *container* maintain a persistent store of all iterators that have been created for it! You can try and think up a data structure yourself that would behave the way you want and see how you would do it. (Try a BST or a deque, perhaps.)